# Unity Vuforia Video size is larger than the image target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I was following the Vuforia's video playback sample and everything was working fine.
But in the sample when I replace my own image_target/video with a dimension of 500x732,  Video's dimension becomes larger than the image target.

For your note, my image target scale is also 500.

- I have worked around on the VideoPlaybackBehaviour.cs script like below.

  ```
                  int videoWidth = mVideoPlayer.GetVideoWidth();
                  int videoHeight = mVideoPlayer.GetVideoHeight();
                  if (videoWidth > 0 && videoHeight > 0){
                  float aspect = videoHeight / (float) videoWidth;                        
                  transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f * aspect);
              }
  ```
- I have also created a plane under ImageTarget and moved the video inside it.
- And also tried by giving both ImageTarget and video the same scale size.
- Also tried by giving scale as zero to the Video component.

but nothing works!

Can anyone please help me on how to resize and play the video within the image target in Unity 3D?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens.  Vuforia doesn't resize the video based on the Image target's resolution.

One hack you can do at your end is to resize your video to a lower dimension.

Incase if you are going to ask question on Vuforia, please do it in Vuforia's forum to keep it live.

Already the same question has been asked in forum but the neither/nor answers from their support team doesn't provided the solution for era's.

You can find those links below

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity-3-extension-technical-discussion/modifying-scale-video-plane-video-playback-sample-app

[Resizing video to plane dimension vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/resize-video-play-same-size-marker)

Please upvote my answer if you find it useful.